# sql server 2008 r2 debugging not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I was able to debug stored procs in Sql server 2008 r2 using management studio until I installed Visual studio 2010 sp1. Did anyone experience similar problem or is it just me?

If so could you please guide me as well on overcoming this issue.

Thanks in advance
Sai

Edit:
Error I get when I run debug is

===================================

Failed to start debugger

===================================

Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. (System.Data)

---

Program Location:

at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.DebugSession.DebugCallbacks.OnSqlInitializeDebuggingEvent(ISqlInitializeDebuggingEvent sqlInitializeDebuggingEvent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.DebugSession.DebugCallbacks.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.IDebugEventCallback2.Event(IDebugEngine2 debugEngine, IDebugProcess2 debugProcess, IDebugProgram2 debugProgram, IDebugThread2 debugThread, IDebugEvent2 debugEvent, Guid& riidEvent, UInt32 attribute)

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 SP1 threw off a lot in SSMS.  Here's the update for SQL Server that'll fix these problems for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041

Comment: looks like am going in loops with this...when I try to install sql server sp1 then it gives me error saying there were some unresolved errors with my sql installation. So when  I try to use Repair sql server installation, it errors again. so looke like am left with no choice but to uninstall and reinstall...